# postgres jdbc client cert user vs db user

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, x509certificate, client-certificates

### Backstory:

I've gotten jdbc to connect to postgres using a client cert.  In java I set the user in the properties, and the driver looks it up in the keystore and sends it along.  All was good.

But I just found out that I won't be getting certs with a CN of pg-user.  The certs I'll be getting will have a CN of pg-user.XYZ.foo.com & pg-user.ABC.foo.com.  This looks like a job for [username maps](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-username-maps.html).  Hey they even have regexp, it'll be perfect.

I got unix user root logging in to postgres as pg-user using a username map and local ident authentication using `psql -d db -U pg-user`.  But in that case postgres knows **BOTH** that the user is root, **AND** is trying to log in as pg-user.

### Problem:

What I can't figure out is how to tell the [postgres jdbc driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41) to grab the cert from the keystore with a CN of pg-user.XYZ.foo.com, but present to postgres as user pg-user.  It appears to be the single argument of `user` that controls both.  Does anyone know how to do this?

[This page](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html) includes a list of the connection options, but it doesn't seem to offer a way to split the user names.  The closest I'm seeing is the option to write my own sslfactory, and I'm **really** hoping to avoid that...

Comment: Have you tried adding the cert to the keystore with an alias of the actual name `pg-user`? I think that will allow you it to find the correct cert even when using the actual DB user name to connect

Comment: I suspect you're going to need a custom SSLSocketFactory. It's not as bad as it seems, though. Otherwise... just patch PgJDBC to add a separate argument for the desired SSL client cert CN and submit your patch on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @harmic's comment I was able to solve this.

Starting with to following three files:

- `pg-user.pem` which has a CN of pg-user.XYZ.foo.com
- `pg-user-chain.pem` which contains the chain certs
- `pg-user.private_key` which contains the private key for the cert

Then I created the pkcs12 file like this:

```
cat pg-user.pem pg-user-chain.pem > cert-and-chain.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ssl_cert.p12 -in cert-and-chain.pem -name pg-user -inkey private_key.pem -passout pass:{password here}
```

After that I declared the user property for the connection to be `pg-user`, and it worked.  In order to test, I altered the regexp in pg_ident to not match, then I could no longer log in, I changed it back and I could.